# Setting the focus into input field

Tags: javascript, focus

I'm trying to set the cursor into the input field. I'm using the functions focus() and select() but I don't know why it isn't working.

Any ideas?

```html
<input type="text" id="test">

<p onmousedown="press()">Test</p>

<script>
  function press() {
    let input = document.getElementById('test');

    input.focus();
    input.select();
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 3):

This was an interesting question that had me investigating a fair bit about the default behaviour of the `mousedown` event and the differences between that and `click`. Thanks!

The answer can actually be explicitly found in the [Notes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOrForeignElement/focus#notes) section of the MDN documentation for `mousedown`:

> If you call HTMLElement.focus() from a mousedown event handler, you must call event.preventDefault() to keep the focus from leaving the HTMLElement

So to fix, do exactly that. Note that I've slightly rewritten your code in order to do that, using `addEventListener` to bind a JS function to the event, which then takes the event object as a parameter. (You could I think have done it your way using the global `event` object - but it's a bad idea to use that. Using `addEventListener` rather than inline JS that evaluates a string attribute and executes it as JS is also a much better, more modern approach.)

```html
<input type="text" id="test">

<p id="button">Test</p>

<script>
  button.addEventListener("mousedown", press);
  function press(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    let input = document.getElementById('test');

    input.focus();
    input.select();
  }
</script>
```

The reason I believe this is necessary is that the `mousedown` event must have a default handler that causes the focus to go on that particular element - and this overrides your attempt to programatically place the focus elsewhere. I'm not 100% sure on that, but it's the most likely explanation that I can come up with.

Note that your original code works completely fine if you'd used the `click` event rather than `mousedown` - and this is more usual. The difference is that `click` only fires when the user releases the mouse button after the initial press, whereas `mousedown` fires instantly when the press happens. I can't see why this distinction would ever be important, and unless for some reason it's vital to you, I would recommend using `click` instead, rather than the fix above.